# How to dynamically schedule with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, cron, google-cloud-functions

I am using reactjs and firebase to host a website and its data.

Now I have a third party API that I need to get and post some data too. Problem is I have to do it at specific times that that API provides for me (planned data updates).

Imagine like dividend release you know the time it will be done but you have to get the data the same second it will be available on the API and the next release will be scheduled in advance and available.

[Firebase suggests using their cloud functions with Google's own cloud Pub/Sub API](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html).
That would be fine but I don't need an hourly or monthly or any other periodic ticker I am looking for my cloud function to set an 'alarm clock' for itself on down to 5-second precision.

How do I reliably dynamically schedule API calls with cloud firebase cloud functions or in some 3rd party CRON API?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a service like https://www.setcronjob.com/documentation/api or similar and just set up a one time job (which some such services support) or schedule an infrequently run job (yearly/monthly/etc.) and then cancel or change it.